# Why did this UIViewController become the First Responder?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, first-responder, motionevent

I've created a new iOS application based on the XCode's "*Single View Application*" template and only modified the `UIViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("motionBegan")
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I shake the device, the function `motionBegan` gets called despite the fact that `canBecomeFirstResponder` returns `false`.

AFAIK the `motionBegan` should be called on an `UIResponder` in the responder chain (in this case starting from the First Responder since we're talking about a non-touch event).

**My questions are:**

- What is the initial First Responder in the "*Single View
  Application*" after the application starts up? (Is it the lastly added subview in the `UIViewController`'s `view`?)
- What object does set the initial First Responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What object does set the initial First Responder?**

The object that set's the initial first responder is UIWindow.

[From the Event Handling Guide for iOS:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1)

> Motion and remote control events. With these events, the window object
>   sends the shaking-motion or remote control event to the first
>   responder for handling. The first responder is described in The
>   Responder Chain Is Made Up of Responder Objects.

**What is the initial First Responder in the "Single View Application" after the application starts up? (Is it the lastly added subview in the UIViewController's view?)**

An event has to happen for the initial first responder to be set, which in this case is the view controller since it overrides the motion began method.

The event is handled with the Responder Chain mechanism and is passed along until it finds an object which can handle it. Touch events and Motion events have slightly different paths see **Event Delivery: The Responder Chain** in the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1) for details.

It looks like that you are following the information in [Detecting Shake-Motion Events with UIEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2). Which states to override these two methods.

```
    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("motionBegan")
}
```

I did a quick test app just the same as yours and noted that setting 'canBecomeFirstResponder() ' had **no bearing** on whether the motion event was handled by the view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote: "`An event has to happen for the initial first responder to be set, which in this case is the view controller since it overrides the motion began method.`". I've overriden the function `motionBegan` in the App Delegate and the View Controller's implementation of `motionBegan` was still called when I shaken the device. **Why wasn't called the App Delegate's implementation**?

Comment: Because the event is passed up the responser chain until a first responder object is found. The last object in the responder chain is the UIApplicationDelegate (since you added the motionBegan() method). Comment out the view controller's motionBegan() method and the Application delegate will handle it.

Comment: Please take a look at my first comment on the @Yuchen Zhong's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34241350

Comment: The responder chain can be empty, at which point the event is is dropped, and not handled at all. For example a touch event on an UIView with userInteractionEnabled set to false.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely my point - based on the fact, that `UIWindow`'s `_firstResponder` is `nil`, the `motionBegan` of the `UIViewController` should not be called, but it is called. Does this mean, that the `_firstResponder` property doesn't hold the *actual* First Responder? Anyway, thank you for your comments.

Comment: No, because if you read the discussion section of  nextResponder() method in the UIResponder class documentation it say's "The  UIResponder class does not store or set the next responder automatically, instead returning nil by default." You really need to be careful about assumptions you make with private API's, I have been bitten more than once this way.

Comment: I still cannot grasp it – as you wrote "`...which in this case is the view controller since it overrides the motion began method.`", does it mean that the `UIWindow` searches all `UIResponder`s in the whole project until it finds a one with `motionBegan` overridden (it doesn't make sense for me)? ...what would be the First Responder of a newly created `UIWindow` – https://bitbucket.org/snippets/7331/78Err ? (What a pitty I cannot +1 your answer.)

Comment: No I believe it only searches the currently displayed view controller, so it does not search your whole project.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your time. I'll try to decompile the `UIApplication` and `UIWindow` classes to find what precisely the steps are from `UIApplication`'s `sendEvent` to my Controller's `motionBegan()`. If I succeed I'll post what I found out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your view controller did not become the first responder. According to the documentation of [canBecomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canBecomeFirstResponder), as long as you override this function and return `false`, in which case you did, it won't become the first responder.

If you try put the following somewhere in your code, for example, in your `motionBegan` function, you will see that it shows that it is indeed not the first responder when it receive the motion event.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesBegan")          // OUTPUT: touchesBegan
    print(isFirstResponder())      // OUTPUT: false
}
```

The reason why this function still gets called is because there is not a first responder which can handle this even anywhere else in your code. According to Apple's documentation about [Motion Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2):

> Motion events use the responder chain to find an object that can handle the event. When the user starts shaking the device, iOS sends the first motion event to the first responder. If the first responder doesn’t handle the event, it progresses up the responder chain.

If you want to know more about how the responder chain, I will recommend you to do some more reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) which explain how the chain is set up and how the events are passed along.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You cited: `...it progresses up the responder chain.`. AFAIK the First Responder is set on `UIWindow`'s property `_firstResponder`. I used private API to inspect the `_firstResponder` property on the application's `keyWindow`. What I found was that the `_firstResponder` is in fact `nil`. I suppose that the responder chain must start from a certain object and progress by calling   `nextResponder()` on the current responder in the chain. But since the `_firstResponder` is `nil`, the function `nextResponder()` can't be called on it (on `nil`).

Comment: Hello @sarasvati, I cannot find any documentation about the implementation detail of the response chain. I think it is just keeping a link list for responder chain. But I don't believe that it is using the first responder as the head of the link list because it is an optional property. And I don't quite understand why you think that it is necessary to use `firstResponder` as the link list head. The two (the first responder and the response chain) could totally be two different objects.

Comment: And as it is explained in the documentation, if there is a first responder, then it will send the event to the first responder; otherwise, it will just go through the responder chain.